# Embedding javascript tag in child page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, master-pages

I have a JavaScript code which links to survey poll page. When I am embedding the JavaScript code in normal aspx page (without master page), I am getting the survey normally without any issues, but when I am embedding the same code in page which uses master page, I am getting blank page.

This way doesn't work: http://gyazo.com/27f38b5b04897cf0b17747eab05cf746

This way works: http://gyazo.com/c69d3b95afe4a0070cd09834e479a97f

### Update

Using `<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Survey/xlaabsolute.asp?p=1")%>' type="text/javascript" />` renders the poll correctly but the button for voting doesn't do any postback http://gyazo.com/b39fcaa8de3438c8c2a625e3816ba4be.

I can see the content http://gyazo.com/b39fcaa8de3438c8c2a625e3816ba4be

Comment: check the url if browser find it, if exist on code html - you can solve this faster with simple check and debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are it's how the script is referenced.

You're using a relative position in your `src` attribute which could potentially change if it's not in a location that allows `Survery/...` to be found. Maybe change it to `/Survey/...` so it always locates the file based on the root path and not where the document currently resides?

You can also make your script tag `runat="Server"` and reference the script using traditional ASP relative links: `src="~/Survey/..."` so it resolves correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can render the page now using the code in the update, from the comment above but clicking 'vote' doesn't do any postback compared to the same button in a page without masterpage. Any idea what can be the reason for that? Thx

Answer (score 0):

The way to resolve the issue and make it work regardless of where the control is being used is to use [ResolveClientUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveclienturl.aspx) as so:

```
<script src='<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Survey/your_script.js")%>' type="text/javascript" />
```

Comment: @lcarus I can see the content now, but the vote button doesn't do any postback. While on the normal page (no master page) the vote button works smoothly.

Comment: @Laziale it's impossible to tell looking at a picture. You'd need to post the relevant source code.